# Logstash Geolocation not functioning properly

Tags: geolocation, logstash

My entire system crashes after I change the configuration to add geo location field.

My system runs correctly when my config looks like this:

```
input {
syslog
{
   host => "localhost4"
   port => 5140
   type => "system"
}


}
filter {

grok { match => { message => [ ".*ipaddr: %{IP:ipaddr}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*dnsname: %{HOSTNAME:query_name}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*mal_rank: %{NUMBER:malrank:int}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*packet_size: %{NUMBER:packetsize:int}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*source_ip: %{IP:sourceip}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*dest_ip: %{IP:dest_ip}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*source_ip: %{IP:src_ip}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*sport: %{NUMBER:sport:int}.*" ] }}

}

output {

elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost4:9200"] }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But when I add the code to my filter

```
input {
syslog
{
   host => "localhost4"
   port => 5140
   type => "system"
}


}
filter {

grok { match => { message => [ ".*ipaddr: %{IP:ipaddr}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*dnsname: %{HOSTNAME:query_name}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*mal_rank: %{NUMBER:malrank:int}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*packet_size: %{NUMBER:packetsize:int}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*source_ip: %{IP:sourceip}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*dest_ip: %{IP:dest_ip}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*source_ip: %{IP:src_ip}.*" ] }}
grok { match => { message => [ ".*sport: %{NUMBER:sport:int}.*" ] }}

geoip {
   source => "ipaddr"
   target => "geoip"
   add_tag => ["geoip"]
   database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
 }
}

output {

elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost4:9200"] }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I can run the curl command and get the correct output

```
curl http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.04.19/_mapping/system/field/geoip.location?pretty
```

and returned:

```
{
  "logstash-2016.04.19" : {
   "mappings" : {
      "system" : {
    "geoip.location" : {
      "full_name" : "geoip.location",
      "mapping" : {
        "location" : {
          "type" : "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

But instead of getting anything, my logstash stops reading from the syslog.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You see nothing from your stdout{} output either?

Comment: Instead of so many groks (each of which is running a small regexp against your larger message field), look for a way to apply a single regexp.  You might also be able to use the kv{} filter to parse the string.

Comment: I am not seeing anything from my stdout{}. I have combined the groks together, but everything tends to die when I do that. I'll have to look up the kv{} filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the delay is, but if I let the system wait for about an hour it starts processing logs again. I just wanted to to confirm that this code does function properly.